# 'MKMapView' / 'showsUserLocation = true' causing error with modal segue

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, viewdidload

I am developing a small map application which allows users to view their current location. I have the relevant code to perform this and it seems to work as expected:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    // CLlocation
    var location: CLLocation!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    // Map variables
    var searchController:UISearchController!
    var annotation:MKAnnotation!
    var localSearchRequest:MKLocalSearchRequest!
    var localSearch:MKLocalSearch!
    var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!
    var error:NSError!
    var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation!
    var pinAnnotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!

    // IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var placesMap: MKMapView!

    // Location function
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateqLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        self.placesMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print("Error code: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.placesMap.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

However, when I launch a modal segue to the 'About' page, from a popover (pictured below), the app crashes:

[image]

I viewed the error given to me in the terminal, this was

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Xcode pointed me to this particular line in my viewDidLoad function:

```
    self.placesMap.showsUserLocation = true
```

When I delete that particular line from my code, the location feature no longer functions, this is obvious. I have checked the outlet to the MKMapView and it seems to be correct.

I really don't know how to avoid this error, or for certainty what is causing it, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this the code for the view that is presented? It looks the like the code for the main view controller. Where is the "about" view presented, that might help us understand why the ````placesMap```` is not present at the time of the crash. Also, there is a typo in the delegate method ````locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateqLocations````

Comment: Its the code for the main view controller which features the map, the about page is presented once the button is pressed on the popover menu in the screenshot I included :) Thanks for letting me know about the typo. I am new to swift and I haven't been able to get around this problem, so if you have any idea how to fix it I would be really grateful

Comment: Basically, something is making the ````placesMap```` deallocate then viewDidLoad is being called. You might try making the ````placesMap```` optional instead of force unwrapping it, so change the ! to a ? and then chain the optional into the call sites of ````placesMap```` (so ````self.placesMap.showsUserLocation```` becomes ````self.placesMap?.showsUserLocation````)

Comment: @NateBirkholz Thanks so much for your reply :) I tried your suggestion and now the About page is presented to me however once it is shown the app crashes again and I get the same error, but this time on this line "self.placesMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)"

Comment: @NateBirkholz added a '?' to that line too and now it doesnt crash at all! Please add your comment as an answer and I will select it :D

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, something is making the `placesMap` deallocate and then `viewDidLoad` is being called. You might try making the `placesMap` optional instead of force unwrapping it, so change the `!` to a `?` on the property and then chain the optional into the call sites of placesMap, so `self.placesMap.showsUserLocation` becomes `self.placesMap?.showsUserLocation` and `self.placesMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)` becomes `self.placesMap?.setRegion(region, animated: true)`